# Any reason not to mark a DLL as CLSCompliant?

Tags: c#, cls-compliant

I am currently testing out Ndepend, and it gives me a warning that assemblies should be marked as CLSCompliant.

Our project is all C#, so it is not really needed.

What I am wondering is: are there any negative effects of marking a dll as clscompliant or should I just disable the warning?

Note I am not asking what CLSCompliant means that is covered here: [What is the 'CLSCompliant' attribute in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570452/what-is-clscompliant-attribute-in-c)

Comment: actually marking your assemblies is a suggestion for code improvement in "effective C#" by Bill Wagner - if you need arguments for your boss. see: http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Ways-Improve-Your/dp/0321245660#reader_0321245660

Comment: FxCop recommends to mark assemblies as CLS compliant, as well. That said, be aware that you can mark assemblies as CLS compliant as a whole, and then exclude single types or members within those assemblies with a `[CLSCompliant(false)]` attribute. This can be necessary if you also want to return or accept some types from 3rd party libraries that are not CLS compliant on their own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of those subtle cases... CLS compliance is probably of *most* importance to library authors, who can't control who the caller is. In your case, you state "our project is all C#", in which case you are right: it isn't needed. It adds restrictions (for example, on unsigned types) which might (or might not) affect representing your data in the most obvious way.

So: if it adds no value to you ***whatsoever***, then frankly: turn that rule off. If you can add it for free (no code changes except the attributes), then maybe OK - but everything is a balance - effort vs result. If there is no gain here, don't invest time.

If you are a library author (merchant or OSS), then you should follow it.

Answer (score 2):

There are several C# features that are not CLS compliant, for example unsigned types. Since several languages are case insensitive, there must be no types and members that differ only by case, e.g. `MyObject` and `myObject`, and several other features. Thus, if you don't plan to work with other .NET languages there is no reason to mark your code as `CLSCompliant`.

Answer (score 1):

The only negative effects would be compiler errors when your code is marked as `CLSCompliant`, but it is not.