# Can you have both C# AND VB application form in one project solution

Tags: c#, vb.net

Is it possible to create a C# splash screen and have the rest of the forms in vb in the same solution?

Comment: Yes. You can create an .exe in C# that shows the splash screen and then runs a VB.NET .exe. But the question is, why? Regardless, one VS Solution can contain a C# project and a VB.NET project.

Comment: Yes you can, you need to learn about CLS compliant. Then you can reference dlls written in VB from C# : [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828575/why-should-i-write-cls-compliant-code), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570452/what-is-the-clscompliant-attribute-in-net)

Comment: Yes, but why on earth would you want to do that?  It would make *much* more sense to just pick one language and stick with it.  There is no advantage to this (since you're clearly making both parts yourself).

Comment: For what it's worth, it would take about the same amount of time to ***try it out yourself*** than ask this question here.

Comment: @Archer, I think the OP is doing it like that because c# does not support splash screens.

Comment: @preciousbetine It's actually trivial to make a splash screen in C# (almost identical to in VB.Net).

Comment: `... but why on earth would you want to do that?` it might seem strange to some people, but alternating between both languages is a good way to keep your skills up to date. That aside, I do find it easier to develop a UI in VB, and a backend in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since Visual Basic and C# both are .NET languages (and both supported by the CLR), you can easily interop between the two and use them within the same application (e.g. calling C# from Visual Basic and vice versa) and solution:

```
Solution
- YourCSharpProject
- YourVisualBasicProject
```

In your specific scenario, it sounds like the two would be completely different areas of an application, so there's nothing from preventing the landing screen to be written using C# and simply navigating to another separate screen backed by Visual Basic.